# Group ever 4 rows with over lap

Tags: t-sql

Sorry for the vague title but I'm not sure how to phrase the question. What I want to do is sum a column in groups if every 4 records, but the groupings will overlap

```
 Game       Strikeouts
    1.                 25
    2.                 10
    3.                 10
    4.                 11
    5.                 16
```

Show the first group would be games 1-4 and sum would be 56, second group would be 2-5 and sun would 47, and so on all the way down to the last record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option

```
Select Game
      ,Strikeouts = sum(Strikeouts) over (Order By Game ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 3 FOLLOWING ) 
 From  YourTable
 Order By Game
```

Returns

```
Game    Strikeouts
1       56
2       47
3       37
4       27
5       16
```

Answer (score 3):

I simply added the values of the next 3 rows to the actual row:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST (
  Game int
 ,Strikeouts int
)
INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES 
(1,25),(2,10),(3,10),(4,11),(5,16)

-- act. row + 3 following rows
SELECT Game, Strikeouts + LEAD(Strikeouts,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY Game) + LEAD(Strikeouts,2,0) OVER (ORDER BY Game) + LEAD(Strikeouts,3,0) OVER (ORDER BY Game) as Strikeouts
FROM #TEST
```

Output:

```
Game |Strikeouts
-----+-----------
  1  |        56
  2  |        47
  3  |        37
  4  |        27
  5  |        16
```

Lag was introduced with SQL Server 2012